# How to perform base-5 addition , when negative place values are given?

Tags: number-systems, digital-design

In a base-5 number system having the digits T,M,0,1,2 and their place values are -2,-1,0,+1,+2 respectively, then:

1. What is the maximum decimal value that can be formed?
2. (MT01) + (1TM0) = ??

This question was given in a recruitment test of a VLSI company.. please suggest an answer..

Comment: I vote to close this since the question is not clear.  How the answerer equated T,M,0,1,2 with 3,4,0,1,2 is a mystery.  The OP's "their place values are -2,-1,0,+1,+2" is at odds with the answerers "Just multiply each digit with corresponding place value, i.e. T*(5^-2) + M*(5^-1) + 0*(5^0) + 1*(5^1) + 2*(5^2)" assertion (e.g. 5^2) != 2).

Answer (score 0):

### > Explanation:

The implementation is very same as decimal concept in base10. Just multiply each digit with corresponding place value, i.e. T*(5^-2) + M*(5^-1) + 0*(5^0) + 1*(5^1) + 2*(5^2).

Base-5 number system digits: 0,1,2,3,4.
Based on place values given, in order to get max decimal value, we can say: M=4 & T=3. And thus below are the answers:

```
1) Max decimal value = **55.92**
2) (MT01) + (1TM0) = (4301)base5 + (1340)base5 = (796)base10 -- decimal value
                                               = **(11141)base5**
```

Comment: The values of M & T are defined, how can we change those values

Comment: Ok. Tell me what are the members of a base 10 number system (i.e. a decimal number system) : 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 right? Similarly the members of a base 5 number system iis : 0,1,2,3,4. So leaving 0,1,2, the only things we are left is 3 & 4. So either M can be 3& T can be 4, or M can be 4 & T can be 3. But there is a condition asking for max decimal value & hence M=4 & T=3.

Comment: Please understand that M,T,0,1,2 are 5 different numbers in the number system.